# Game on the tree

Tags: game-theory, trees

There's a problem from programming competition which already finished:
http://codeforces.com/contest/458/problem/F

Two weeks already passed but still nobody solved it yet - in fact you can see here http://codeforces.com/problemset?order=BY_SOLVED_ASC that this is the only problem in the set of about 2000 problems that was not solved yet.

The problem itself follows.

*Pieguy and Piegirl are playing a game. They have a rooted binary tree, that has a property that each node is either a leaf or has exactly two children. Each leaf has a number associated with it.
On his/her turn a player can choose any two leafs that share their immediate parent, remove them, and associate either of their values with their parent, that now became a leaf (the player decides which of the two values to associate). The game ends when only one node (the one that was the root of the tree) is left.
Pieguy goes first, and his goal is to maximize the value that will be associated with the root when the game ends. Piegirl wants to minimize that value. Assuming that both players are playing optimally, what number will be associated with the root when the game ends?*

Can you help me how to mathematically solve this minimax problem? Do we need to use any advanced concepts from game theory to solve this problem?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: The mathematics is quite easy; this is basic min-max, if I am not mistaken. The problem is rather computational complexity and programming optimization, and thus, your question does not belong here, but rather on programmers.stackexchange

Comment: No, it's not "basic min-max". I didn't use any programming terms and problem is formulated purely mathematically.

Comment: @IgorDemidov, what kind of answer do you expect? Is it a description of algorithm solving the problem or the result on its complexity? I believe the algorithm itself is quite easy to construct..

Comment: The operations respect collapses of the linear order, so if you can solve the problem for values in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ then you can determine whether the value should be greater than $c$ or not, and use binary search to find the fair value.

Comment: Suppose you classify games with $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ values by the parity of the number of moves left, who wins if Pieguy moves first, and who wins if Piegirl moves first. If you can classify the results of joining pairs of games of these types, this gives a fast recursive solution (as opposed to the naive exponential recursive algorithms). So, are any of the pairs undetermined?

Comment: In each step, there is a finite set of moves. For each move, you reach a smaller tree, and for this, (by recursion), you know already who will win in that game. Therefore, as a PROGRAMMING problem, it is quite straightforward. The hard part is to optimize it to run in decent speed (I guess it is about isomorphisms for binary trees that is the key thing).

Comment: I think it is not determined who wins if you join together two first person wins so that one has an even size and the other has an odd size, so one has to subdivide the games into more than those categories.

Comment: According to the links this has now been solved by four people on that programming challenges website. This is a basic min-max problem which can be sped up using various well-known tricks. It is not research-level. It has been upvoted because it is a puzzle that is easy to understand, and hard to solve efficiently if you are not sophisticated with computers. Can we close this question now?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question what you mean by a "mathematical" solution.
From my experience in programming competitions (and, having a look on the problems over at project Euler), there is usually no "nice" closed-form solution to problems of this type. Thus, don't expect a formula, 
a significant amount of clever dynamic programming will be required to solve hard test cases.

*Since you have not provided even a brute-force algorithm, 
I take it that you wonder about how to even formulate a naive algorithm.*

Below is a min-max approach, with bad complexity, but it is a 
"mathematical" solution. For me, a "mathematical" solution is something that can be solved by a specific algorithm given enough time.

```
(* Base case optimal value in optimal move *)
maxPossible[{l_Integer,r_Integer}]:=Max[l,r];
minPossible[{l_Integer,r_Integer}]:=Min[l,r];

(* Construct all subtrees, by applying op (Min or Max) on pairs of leaves.*)
SubTrees[tree_List,op_]:=Module[{l,r,pos},
    pos=Position[tree,{l_Integer,r_Integer}];
    Table[ReplacePart[tree,p->op@Part[tree,Sequence@@p]],{p,pos}]
];

maxPossible[tree_List]:=maxPossible[tree]=Module[{strees},
    (* All possible moves Max can do. *)
    strees = SubTrees[tree,Max];

    (* Max wants to maximize over all possible subsequent moves. *)
    Max[minPossible/@strees]
];

minPossible[tree_List]:=minPossible[tree]=Module[{strees},
    (* All possible moves. *)
    strees = SubTrees[tree,Min];

    Min[maxPossible/@strees]
];

(* Test cases, as on website *)
testTree1={5,10};
testTree2={{5,20},10};
testTree3={{1,2},{3,4}};
testTree4={{{7,8},15},{7,{9,11}}};

maxPossible[testTree1]
maxPossible[testTree2]
maxPossible[testTree3]
maxPossible[testTree4]
```

The output is as expected. It is easy to modify the code, so that actual gameplay can be recorded. The last game for example, gives the following sequence of moves:

```
--- {{{7,8},15},{7,{9,11}}}
--- {{{7,8},15},{7,11}}
--- {{{7,8},15},7}
--- {{8,15},7}
--- {8,7}
--- {8}
```

I think you will have better luck over at programmers.SE, since this question is similar to Project Euler questions (if you heard about it).

Comment: Is this just a brute force search with memoization? Whether something runs in $n \log n$ time or $2^n$ time is not just a programming problem, nor is discovering the faster algorithm. Not all families of finite problems are mathematically trivial. "PRIMES is in P" was published in the Annals of Mathematics even though testing whether any particular number is prime is a finite calculation. Figuring out a reasonably fast algorithm for playing this game is a math problem, not just a programming problem.

Comment: This is brute force. Yes, of course it is not always trivial, but since the problem is from an actual programming competition and not an unsolved problem, the question might be better asked over at programmers.SE. Same as IMO problems belong to math.SE, and not here...

Comment: If you really think this is off-topic, you shouldn't post a supposed answer. However, there are many differences between this problem and an IMO problem. It shouldn't be dismissed as trivial and straightforward just because particular cases are finite and you see that a brute force algorithm with a horrible running time exists.

Comment: I interpreted the question as "Is this problem of minmax type?", as indicated by the comments. This question is not really out of scope, IMHO, and I thought I provide an answer to that. For optimization, I think one will have more luck at another SE.

Comment: You commented that this problem is easy and straightforward, but you have only shown a brute force approach that is like trial division for factorization. That's not progress. That's not helpful. Asking for a translation of this game into known parts of combinatorial game theory is a very reasonable mathematical question. Coding up a very slow brute force search is neither an answer nor mathematics. If you can use your code to find some patterns and make some conjectures about the structure of the problem, that would be mathematics.

Comment: If you read the question, it is nowhere stated that it is the complexity that is the problem. OP ask for a "mathematical" solution, and since OP does not indicate that (s)he has even a naive solution, I interpreted the question as "can one mathematically formulate a procedure that gives a solution?" I provide such an answer. 
In this type of problem, there is usually no short-cut formula that quickly solves the problem. Even with lots of game theory, it is still a PROGRAMMING task, to bring down the complexity.

Comment: The question doesn't need to say that there is a difference between a usable algorithm and an unusable one like brute force search. It is obvious that brute force takes a finite but ridiculously large amount of time. Writing programming in all caps repeatedly is just strange, not convincing. This is a mathematical problem to determine the structure of this family of games so that a fast algorithm can be produced. If someone asks how to factor a 200 digit number, would you say "Here is trial division. Now it is a PROGRAMMING problem?" That is what you have done here.

Comment: @DouglasZare: As expressed, I interpret the question as asking for a naive implementation (this is how I interpret "mathematical" solution). 
I also believe MO is not the best place to find a solution that meets the speed requirements. Both these points has been clarified in answer.

Comment: Traditionally, mathematical problems do not have to be formalized. But once you solved it--nobody would have any doubt that you did something mathematically significant.